# Diverging loss in Keras with custom loss

Tags: python, keras, deep-learning

I have a fully connected feed-forward network implemented with Keras. Initially, I used binary cross-entropy as the loss and the metric, and Adam optimizer as follows

```
adam = keras.optimizers.Adam(lr=0.01, beta_1=0.9, beta_2=0.999, epsilon=None, decay=0.0, amsgrad=False)
model.compile(optimizer=adam, loss='binary_crossentropy', metrics=['binary_crossentropy'])
```

This model trains well and gives good results. In order to get better results I want to use a different loss function and metric as below,

```
import keras.backend as K

def soft_bit_error_loss(yTrue, yPred):
    loss = K.pow(1 - yPred, yTrue) * K.pow(yPred, 1-yTrue)
    return K.mean(loss)

def ber(yTrue, yPred):
    x_hat_train = K.cast(K.greater(yPred, 0.5), 'uint8')
    train_errors = K.cast(K.not_equal(K.cast(yTrue, 'uint8'), x_hat_train), 'float32')
    train_ber = K.mean(train_errors)
    return train_ber
```

I use it to compile my model as below

```
model.compile(optimizer=adam, loss=soft_bit_error_loss, metrics=[ber])
```

However, when I do that, the loss and the metric diverge after some training, everytime as in the following pictures.

[image: custom loss]

[image: ber]

What can be the cause of this?

Comment: I think your loss is non-differentiable, I'm surprised your network even trained

Comment: @JosephBudin loss is soft_bit_error. I think it is differentiable.  Here yPred is a soft value. ber is metric only used for model selection.

Comment: Oh ok, my bad, I read too fast

Comment: Have you tried decreasing the learning rate ?

Comment: What if you change `loss = K.pow(1 - yPred, yTrue) * K.pow(yPred, 1-yTrue)` to `loss = K.switch(yTrue == 1, 1 - yPred, yPred)`? (assuming `yTrue` consists of either zeros or ones).

Answer (score 1):

Your loss function is very unstable, look at it:

[image]

Where I replaced `y_pred` (variable) with `x` and `y_true` (constant) with `c` for simplicity.

As your predictions approach zero, at least one operation will tend to 1/0, which is infinite. Although by the limits theory you can know the result is ok, Keras doesn't know the "whole" function as one, it calculates derivatives based on the basic operations used.

So, one easy solution is the one pointed by @today:

```
loss = K.switch(yTrue == 1, 1 - yPred, yPred)
```

It's exactly the same function (difference only when `c` is not zero or 1).

Also, even easier, for `c=0` or `c=1`, it's just a plain `loss='mae'`.